# Meaning of に in アルバイトの人などに売る数

Tags: grammar, particle-に

From [here](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010862671000/k10010862671000.html):

> コンビニを経営している人は、売らなければならない数を会社から言われて、アルバイトの人など**に売る**数を言う店もあると話しています。
>   Convenince store managers say that they are told how much they must sell by the company, and (there are even stores that say the amount to sell **to** part-time workers) / (there are even stores that say the amount **for** part time workers to sell).

The article is talking about how student workers are complaining about sales targets for 恵方巻.

I'm not sure about the last part. What does アルバイトの人に売る数 mean here? Does に mean **to** or **for**? Does the shop have a quota for selling 恵方巻 **to** its workers. Or is it a quota **for** the workers to sell? How can I know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not parsing it correctly, I'm afraid. It's parsed:

> ｛（アルバイトの人など**に**）（売る数を）**言う**｝店もある

The に in アルバイトの人など**に** means "to".

*lit.* There are stores that **tell** the amount to sell **to** their part-time workers.
⇒ Some stores tell their part-time workers how many (恵方巻) they should sell.

---

Btw, the whole sentence is parsed:

> コンビニを経営している人は、『（売らなければならない数を会社から言われて、アルバイトの人などに売る数を言う）店もある。』と話しています。

Comment: Thanks. Is there a grammatical reason that に must go with 言う rather than with 売る? Or have you chosen this parsing simply because it is the most logical? Is there a grammatical reason why my parsings are wrong?

Comment: I don't think there's a grammatical reason. You parse it this way because it is the most logical and makes the most sense.